# Foot Deformation When Moving Legs in Pose Mode

Tags: rigging

I'm new to Blender and to this forum. I know very little about Blender, but have been studying and following along several beginner level tutorials. Thank you in advance for any suggestions or help offered!

My feet look okay in Edit and Object mode but when I go to move them in Pose mode, the "heels" of them extrude and deform terribly. I've been trying for days to find an answer and to solve it on my own. Any suggestions would be much appreciated! If you need more information to be able to answer, please don't hesitate to ask :)

[image]

Comment: please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/   some other bones must have influence on your foot, you should select your foot in Edit mode and use Remove from All Groups in the Properties panel > Data > Vertex Groups (down arrow on the right of the vertex groups list), then assign again to the foot group or in Weight Paint mode

Comment: Thank you for your response! I'm going to try this out when I have the chance and will post results.